# JNA memory leak in Library.Handler.invoke

Tags: java, winapi, memory-leaks, jna

Originally, I thought memory is leaking in the native library, but it seems that it is not. I use JNA to access Winapi's User32 library. Certain functions happen to be called little bit too often, specifically `GetWindowText` and `GetWindowTextLength`. Well, I can see some ways to reduce the amount of calls to these functions but I'd prefer to remove the leak first.

Here's the leak stack trace:

[image: image description]
<sup>The green pluses mark where my program starts.</sup>

As you can see somehow, `java.lang.reflect.Method` instances are being stacked high. After 5-10 minutes of runtime, there's 44MB of them! This is way too much, especially for a program that should run in background, which is what my program should do.

Can I do something else about it? Is this JNA bug? Or is it just garbage collector being too lazy?

Comment: Have you tried to tweak the garbage collector? Or are you running with "all default settings"?

Comment: @Jägermeister I'm quite new to Java, anything apart from algorithms is unknown territory to me, so yes, I compile with everything all default. I'll try to reproduce this in standalone program to makes sure it's not my program's fault.

Comment: I am not talking about **compiler** options (as there are close to zero "interesting" options for a java compiler; this is not gcc where -O1 works great and -O3 breaks everything). I am talking about the various switches that you can apply when starting the JVM. See here for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html But of course, this requires a good understanding of how GC works. So lets hope somebody else comes by and give more profound advice on your specific problem.